# How to resolve "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException" error?

Tags: java

This is my code. It is a random string generator. When I run it, if the number of letters and characters added together are less than the desired amount of digits, I get an error code as shown below. Can someone help me on fixing this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class list {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Random num = new Random();
        System.out.println("How many characters do you want?");
        Scanner Digits = new Scanner(System.in);
        int digits = Integer.parseInt(Digits.nextLine());
        System.out.println("How many different numbers do you want? 1-10 please");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(Digits.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Which letters do you want? One at a time, press enter after each letter. If done, just press enter.");
        List<String> characters = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Add your characters.");
            String character = Digits.nextLine();
            if (character.equals("")) {
                break;
            } else {
                characters.add(character);
            }
        }

        List<Object> andrew = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (int x = 0; x < digits; x++) {
            andrew.add(num.nextInt(number));
            andrew.add(characters.get(x));
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < andrew.size(); x += 2) {
            System.out.print(andrew.get(x));
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at list.main(list.java:33)
```

Answer (score 1):

An `IndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs when you try to select a value from an array that goes beyond its size. In this example, you're trying to get the value at [3]. You can read this much off the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
```

Arrays in java begin at index `[0]`, not index `[1]`, and so an array of length 3 will only have indices `[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]`.

Trying to get the value at `[3]` when the array only extends to `[2]` will cause this error.

HOWEVER, the other answer is actually wrong about where the problem is. The stack trace says it's at line 33 which is this:

```
andrew.add(characters.get(x));
```